# Rails: has_many :through. Need to return records that have unique column value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my User model:

```
has_many :followed_recommendations, :through => :followed_users, :source => :recommendations, class_name: Recommendation
```

A recommendation has a movie_id column. A user can get multiple recommendations for the same movie but I would like to return only 1.

So I need a way to get only the :followed_recommendations that have a unique movie_id value but not sure how to do this. The example I keep seeing coming up is:

```
has_many :products, -> { distinct }, through: :orders
```

But that is looking at the full product record whereas I just want distinct by one column.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
 has_many :followed_recommendations, ->{group(:movie_id)}, :through => :followed_users, :source => :recommendations, class_name: Recommendation
```

Comment: I'm getting PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "recommendations.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Answer (score 0):

You have a `movie_id` column in your `Recommendation` model, so I assume you have this association.

```
class Recommendation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :movie
end
```

Then you could use the way with `distinct` like you posted in your question.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :followed_recommendations, :through => :followed_users, :source => :recommendations, class_name: Recommendation
  has_many :followed_recommended_movies, -> { distinct }, :through => :followed_recommendations, :class_name => Movie, source: :movie
end
```